# Easy one on transitive relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

So I've got this one on my home work:

*Which of the following are equivalence relations on the set of $Z$ (integers)?*

And it presents this relation among others:

$xEy$ if and only if $x^2=y^2.$

So I simplify this into simply $x=y$...Because why not? So I get that, well, every $(a,b)$ is indeed reflexive and symmetrical but when I come to the transitive part, I'm a bit confused seeing as $(a,b)$=$(b,c)$=$(a,c)$ for every $(a,b)$. For example $(3,3)$, $(a,b)=(3,3)$ so $(b,c)=(3,3)$ which implies that $(a,c)=(3,3)$ seeing as 3 only appears once, of course.

Does that make the relation transitive and therefore the relation is also a equivalence relation?

Comment: $(-3)^2=3^2$. Does that mean that $3=-3$?

Comment: It actually simplifies to $|x| = |y|$ if you take square roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful: $x= -y$ also qualifies. That is, $xRy \iff x^2 = y^2 \iff x = y \text{ or } x = -y$.

So, in any case, if $aRb, bRc$, with $a, b, c  \in \mathbb Z$, then $a^2 = b^2$, and $b^2 = c^2$. Hence $a^2 = c^2$, giving us $aRc$. So the relation is transitive.